# rsync not syncing certain directories

Tags: rsync

I am running the following rsync command nightly:

```
rsync -varhR --delete --stats --files-from=files_to_include / /media/drive/snapshots/nightly.0
```

Here is the `files_to_include` file

```
home/
etc/
var/www/
```

If I take a look in `/var/www/html/` I have several folders and files

If I take a look in `/media/drive/snapshopshots/nightly.0/var/www/html/`, its completely empty. No files or directories here.

So for some reason, that html folder is not getting sync'ed.

I manually tried running this command:

`rsync -varhR --delete --stats /var/www/ /media/drive/snapshots/nightly.0`

And then it sync'ed correctly. So something is going on with the `--files-from` flag I guess. Are there some sort of limitations to that option?

Comment: how are you running this command? is it a cronjob?

Comment: yes, cronjob as root

Comment: Did you try with `--files-from=files_to_include` on the command line? Did you try with a different `--files-from` file? If you created `files_to_include` on a Windows machine, did you check for spurious CRs?

Comment: Also run it with `-v` to get verbose output.  This will tell you WHAT its trying to sync.  I was able to run that exact command (with a different destination) with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If running it from cron, it is best to fully specify the path to `files_to_include`

I usually redirect output to a file so I can later check for error messages

```
0 23 * * * /a/b/rsync ... --files-from=/c/d/f2inc ... > /tmp/rsync.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make those paths in the include file absolute. i.e. /var/www/ instead of var/www/

Comment: The paths in the include file are relative to whatever you specify in as the source directory in the command, which in my case is "/". If I added a / to the front of them, the paths would end up "//var/www"